# Accessing parent object fields in trigger handler class

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I am Writing a trigger handler class for a after insert trigger for a object 'A'.After passing trigger.new to a function in handler class, I am able to access A's field but its parent object fields are all null.How can I access  parent objects fields without passing the Id from trigger itself along with trigger.new variable.

Here is the sample trigger::

```
if(trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){


      TriggerHandler.handleAfterInsert(trigger.new);

}
```

here is the handler class::

```
  public class DedupeTriggerHandler{
    public static void handleAfterInsert(List<A__c >AList) {
    // accessing parent objects field here

           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? I do similar things in my classes to access child object records. You basically need to get a set of all the Ids for A__c and then do a SOQL query in order to see child object records associated with A__c. Below, I'm using "Contact" as an example child object.

```
public static void handleAfterInsert(List<A__c> AList) {
    Set<Id> aIds = new Set<Id>(); //set for holding the Ids in AList ("trigger.new")

    // 1. Get a list of all A__c Id's in the trigger
    for (A__c ac : AList) {
        // Add the Id to set
        aIds.add(ac.Id);
        System.Debug('^^^^^## A__c Id added to list: ' + ac.Id);
    }

    // 2. Loop through all A__c affected by trigger (using one SOQL query)
    for (A__c ac : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Contacts) FROM A__c WHERE Id in :aIds]) {
        // You should now be able to see child table data here:
        for (Contact c : ac.Contacts) {
            ...
            ...
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to access the parent object fields rather than child objects fields.You can access the child object fields using inner soql query.Usually we can access the parent object fields using '.'(dot) operator.But in this case it is not working!

Comment: I may still be misunderstanding, but in that case (in my experience), you just need to build a map of the parent IDs. So if you're dealing with Contacts and want to get Account sObject fields, you'd just loop through the trigger.new to get the AccountId and add it to the map. Then you could do a SOQL to get the Account fields you need (i.e. [Select ID, Name, Owner from Account where ID in : AccountIDs]). The thing is, with trigger.new, trigger.oldmap, etc, I _don't think_ you have direct access to Parent or Child sObjects until you do a SOQL from the database.

Comment: that's right   ''with trigger.new, trigger.oldmap  you don't have direct access to Parent or Child sObjects until you do a SOQL from the database''.